# Raise validation error from child form on parent form in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

Let's say I have this form:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class NameForm(forms.form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=200)

class NameAgeForm(NameForm):
    age = forms.IntegerField()

    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        if data.get('age') == 24 and data.get('name') == 'Nebu':
            raise ValidationError({'name': "You can't pick that name and age, they are mine!"})
```

The thing is, I have a sub-form where validation is happening.
But I want my field error being shown at the NameForm.

**Sidenote** I can't access the parent form and therefore the solution must come from the child.

Now, is this possible?

Comment: You are right about that.. will easy fix

Comment: In fact, I will redesign my question so it is more obvious

Comment: I don't understand your question. How are you using `NameForm` and `NameAgeForm`?

Comment: Yes, I understand my question is a bit vague. I am currently updating it to give a better impression of my situation. To be short, it involves Wagtail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.clean) method on your NameAgeForm It must add custom validation for each field.  For [field-specific](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) validation, This field validation specific to your current form, We don’t want to put it into the ChildForm. Instead, we write a cleaning method in ParentForm. So Django doesn't help you.